# Linux/Ubuntu: Wheel events not triggering when context menu is open

Tags: linux, firefox-addon, xul

This is the code I am running:

```
  window.removeEventListener('wheel', onwheel, false);
  window.removeEventListener('mousedown', ondown, false);

  function onwheel(e) {
    console.info('wheeled, e:', e);
  }

  function ondown(e) {
    console.info('downed, e:', e);
  }

  window.addEventListener('wheel', onwheel, false);
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', ondown, false);
```

If I roll the wheel while over browser window, the wheel event triggers.  However my intention is to detect wheel events only while right mouse button is being held down.

The issue is, holding the right mouse button down opens the context menu panel, this is good and expected, but now wheel events do not trigger unless my mouse is over the context menu that opened. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This behavior does not happen on Windows systems even if the context menu is visible (sidenote: on windows the context menu does not show until mouse up, but i forced it to show to test this, and wheel events triggered even when my mouse was not over that context menu).

Comment: This is reproducible on my VM, I'm baffled too though I had a similar situation in the past.

Answer (score 1):

### UI issues:

The UI you describe sounds like it is a bit counter to what most people will be expecting.  It is unusual to use a two fingered mouse button + wheel combination. Users are very familiar with using <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> as modifiers for buttons and mouse actions. You are combining 2 already used UI controls (scroll wheel, and right-click) in a way that is confusing to users.  In addition it is attempting to override the already existing actions for both of these controls. In my opinion, it would be better to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-scroll-wheel as this does not have a default action. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-scroll-wheel's default action is zoom and <kbd>ALT</kbd>-scroll-wheel leaves the UI in a state where the next keyboard input is considered to be a menu selection.

### Which `window`:

You do not say: what is the context in which this code is running?  Is it a frame script? Or more explicitly, which `window` are you using to set up the listener? Are you using the document `window`, the tab `window`, or the overall browser `window`? Are you sure that the one you are using is the same on all OS types? I would expect that if you use the overall browser `window`, you should get all events, even those while the mouse is not over the context menu. If you are using one of the others, then it is not that unreasonable for you to only receive events when the modal context menu is focused. If you did not specifically obtain the overall browser `window`, then the `window` you are using is probably one of the others.

### Prevent the context menu from displaying upon `mousedown`:

A simple solution to this should be to prevent the context menu from opening upon `mousedown`. Either [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
function ondown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.info('downed, e:', e);
}
```

or [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```
function ondown(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.info('downed, e:', e);
}
```

should prevent the context menu from being displayed upon the `mousedown` event. Assuming that it is not displayed based on another event this code would prevent it from ever being displayed. Actually, given that this code does not check for which mouse button, or any possible modifiers to the button, it will `stopPropagation()` or `preventDefault()` on ALL `mousedown` events, which is not desirable in real-world code. In other words, this is a very simplified example and you expand it so that you are only usurping the events which you are actually targeting.

Comment: Thanks Mayken. Conext is XUL Window of type `navigator:browser`. Thanks for suggestion to change the to using alt/ctrl + scroll however my addon is established for sometime now to behave with mouse right held down and wheel. It works as expected in Windows. Mac is similar in situation to Linux but not exactly. Thanks also for prevent context menu suggestion however I can't prevent the context menu from showing on mouse down as the workflow of many users on Linux/Mac is to right mouse down and expect menu shown (and further, maybe right mouse up on the item they want to select).

Comment: So I just need to make it such that if scroll wheel happens the event propogates to the XUL window, I did try adding event listener to the context menu however it only triggers if their mouse is over the conext menu, and because i already attached to DOM Window its triggering twice. So my big issue is how come no events are triggered when context menu is showing and mouse is not over that menu.